# GPO to turn off the screen/display but NOT lock the computer at the same time in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, group-policy, lock-screen

I've recently set-up this GPO policy in AD:
*Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Video and Display Settings > Turn Off the Display (Plugged In or On Battery)* in order to turn off the screen/display.

Unfortunately, although not specified in the policy description, **this policy also LOCKS the computer** - reported by many users (and I then confirmed myself).

Desired state:

1. 10 minutes of user inactivity -> turn off the screen (but no lock!)
2. another 20 minutes (30 total) -> lock the computer (and leave the screen turned off)

Any hints?

Debug info:

- I've got *Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 10 November 2019 Update* installed. I will update to latest if somebody confirms there is such a policy combination to make it work as described.
- By "lock" I mean the state when the user is required to sign-in again with password.

Thank you for help!

Comment: If this is possible entirely entirely depends on what monitors you have.  Windows is going to is gone to lock the user profile based on the settings of the power profile. However that action is only going to happen once per the settings you have them configured

Comment: My non-domain Win10 Home had similar behavior. The fix was two-part. First, un-hiding a power Setting in the Advanced Power Options dialog: [Sleep\System Unattended Sleep Timeout](https://www.google.com/search?q=System+Unattended+Sleep+Timeout&oq=Sy&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j5.16007j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and setting its value higher than the screen timeoout. Not sure how you would translate to GPO.